# How can I modify the code below so the order of Image selection matches the order of Image presentation using swift concurrency?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-concurrency

**This is how the images were selected.**

[image: Order of section]

**This is how they are presented.**

[image: Order of presentation]

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

@MainActor
class ExampleViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    @Published var selectedImages: [RectangleProfileImage] = []
    
    func loadItem(item: PhotosPickerItem) async {
        do {
            let data = try await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self)
            guard let data else { return }
            if let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                self.selectedImages.append(RectangleProfileImage(image: image))
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error loading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.selectedImages.append(RectangleProfileImage(image: Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill"), hasfailed: true))
        }
    }
}



struct ExampleView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ExampleViewViewModel()
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                Text("Select up to 6 images for your profile")
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.selectedImages) {
                        if !$0.hasfailed {
                            $0.rectangleView
                        } else {
                            RectangleFailedImage().rectangleView
                        }
                    }
                    if viewModel.selectedImages.count < 6 {
                        ForEach((viewModel.selectedImages.count...5), id: \.self) { _ in
                            RectanglePlaceHolderImage().rectangleView
                        }
                    }
                }.onChange(of: viewModel.selectedItems) { pickerItems in
                    viewModel.selectedImages.removeAll()
                    for item in pickerItems {
                        Task {
                            await viewModel.loadItem(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
                HStack {
                        PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.selectedItems,
                                     maxSelectionCount: 6,
                                     selectionBehavior: .ordered,
                                     matching: .any(of: [.images, .not(.screenshots)]),
                                     preferredItemEncoding: .automatic,
                                     photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .font(.system(size: 60))
                                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        }.buttonStyle(.borderless)
                            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
    }
}


struct RectanglePlaceHolderImage: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let image = Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
    
    var rectangleView: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 108, height: 134)
            image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 23)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

struct RectangleFailedImage: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let image = Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
    
    var rectangleView: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 108, height: 134)
            image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 32, height: 23)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

struct RectangleProfileImage: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let image: Image
    var hasfailed = false
    
    var rectangleView: some View {
        image
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: 108, height: 134)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest change you can make is to switch

```swift
for item in pickerItems {
  Task {
    await viewModel.loadItem(item: item)
  }
}
```

to

```swift
Task {
  for item in pickerItems {
    await viewModel.loadItem(item: item)
  }
}
```

---

Note: I consider this to be a good use case for using `forEach`, but [some people really hate it](https://forums.swift.org/t/do-we-want-foreach/56929) so it's not in the standard library or AsyncAlgorithms.

```swift
import AsyncAlgorithms

Task {
  await pickerItems.async.forEach(viewModel.loadItem)
}
```

```swift
public extension AsyncSequence {
  @inlinable func forEach(_ body: (Element) async throws -> Void) async rethrows {
    for try await element in self {
      try await body(element)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this fitted what I need perfectly, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you are fetching them concurrently, but adding them to the results in whatever order that they complete. So, you are enjoying concurrency, but the order will not be preserved. E.g., here is your code (refactored into a function of the view model):

```swift
func loadItems1(_ pickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem]) {
    selectedImages.removeAll()

    for item in pickerItems {
        Task {
            await selectedImages.append(imageView(for: item))
        }
    }
}
```

You could obviously fetch them sequentially (i.e., making each request `await` the prior one). That would preserve the order that they were selected. But you lose concurrent retrieval of the images (which could make it much slower if more than one image needed to be retrieved from the cloud). But a sequential fetching of the images might look like:

```swift
func loadItems2(_ pickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem]) async {
    selectedImages.removeAll()
    
    for item in pickerItems {
        await selectedImages.append(imageView(for: item))
    }
}
```

Fortunately, we can remedy this tradeoff between concurrency and preserving the original order. We can allow the images to be fetched concurrently, but then collate the results back into the original order. That is the best of both worlds. E.g.:

```swift
func loadItems3(_ pickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem]) async {
    selectedImages = await withTaskGroup(of: (Int, RectangleProfileImage).self) { group in
        for (index, item) in pickerItems.enumerated() {
            group.addTask { await (index, self.imageView(for: item)) }
        }

        let dictionary = await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
        return pickerItems.indices.compactMap { dictionary[$0] }
    }
}
```

That might look confusing at first glance, but it really is not that bad: The `withTaskGroup` performs the requests concurrently. It returns a tuple of the original index and the result so that the `group.reduce` can build an unordered dictionary, as the results come in, keyed by the original index. Then, the `compactMap` of the `indices` will produce a nicely ordered array of results from that order-independent dictionary. This way you enjoy concurrency, but the final results will be ordered.

For your reference, here is the complete implementation using the above methods:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ExampleViewModel()
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    let maximumToSelect = 6

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                Text("Select up to 6 images for your profile")

                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.selectedImages) {
                        if !$0.hasfailed {
                            $0.rectangleView
                        } else {
                            RectangleFailedImage().rectangleView
                        }
                    }
                    ForEach(viewModel.selectedImages.count ..< maximumToSelect, id: \.self) { _ in
                        RectanglePlaceHolderImage().rectangleView
                    }
                }

                HStack {
                    PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.selectedItems,
                                 maxSelectionCount: maximumToSelect,
                                 selectionBehavior: .ordered,
                                 matching: .any(of: [.images, .not(.screenshots)]),
                                 preferredItemEncoding: .automatic,
                                 photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .font(.system(size: 60))
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class ExampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = [] {
        didSet {
            Task { await loadItems3(selectedItems) }
        }
    }

    @Published var selectedImages: [RectangleProfileImage] = []
}

// MARK: - ExampleError

extension ExampleViewModel {
    enum ExampleError: Error {
        case unableToTransfer
        case unableToCreateImage
    }
}

// MARK: - Private implementation

private extension ExampleViewModel {
    // not used; this is the original current pattern, returning them in a random order

    func loadItems1(_ pickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem]) {
        selectedImages.removeAll()
        for item in pickerItems {
            Task {
                await selectedImages.append(imageView(for: item))
            }
        }
    }

    // not used; this will load them sequentially, which return them in order, but will slow down the process as you lose the concurrency of the image retrieval

    func loadItems2(_ pickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem]) async {
        selectedImages.removeAll()

        for item in pickerItems {
            await selectedImages.append(imageView(for: item))
        }
    }

    // this is used; fetch them concurrently, but collate the results back in the original order

    func loadItems3(_ pickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem]) async {
        selectedImages = await withTaskGroup(of: (Int, RectangleProfileImage).self) { group in
            for (index, item) in pickerItems.enumerated() {
                group.addTask { await (index, self.imageView(for: item)) }
            }

            let dictionary = await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
            return pickerItems.indices.compactMap { dictionary[$0] }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Methods to retrieve assets

private extension ExampleViewModel {
    func imageView(for item: PhotosPickerItem) async -> RectangleProfileImage {
        do {
            return try await RectangleProfileImage(image: image(for: item))
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return RectangleProfileImage(
                image: Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill"),
                hasfailed: true
            )
        }
    }

    func image(for item: PhotosPickerItem) async throws -> Image {
        guard let data = try await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) else {
            throw ExampleError.unableToTransfer
        }

        guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw ExampleError.unableToCreateImage
        }

        return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}
```

Note, I've made some unrelated minor refinements:

- I have renamed the view model for `ExampleView` to just be `ExampleViewModel`;
- I have eliminated the `if viewModel.selectedImages.count < 6 { … }` test and replaced the `...` with `..<`;
- I moved the hardcoded `6` with a constant, so that if you change that parameter in the future, you only have to change it in one spot; and
- I replaced the view’s `onChange` with a `didSet` observer within the view model.

---

While the above solves the order of the results while still enjoying concurrency, it still has two problems:

1. The UI is not updated until all of the images have been fetched. This will be especially problematic if any of the images are being fetched from the cloud.
2. While the user is waiting for the results, they may be inclined to tap the button to select the images again. (The probability that they might do this is exacerbated by the previous point, namely that it might be very slow, and the user may wonder if they selected the photos correctly.) You want to make sure that a new request will cancel the prior one.

So, it might be better to show a `ProgressView` for each pending image request, and then as they individually finish, replace that with the actual image that was fetched. That way:

- the user will receive positive feedback that their request was captured and that their request is underway; and
- they can see progress as the images are downloaded (e.g., if the first three are local, and the next three have to be downloaded, why not show them the local responses immediately while the remote ones are underway?).

Thus, perhaps something like:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ExampleViewModel()
    let columns = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]
    let maximumToSelect = 6

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyVStack {
                Text("Select up to 6 images for your profile")

                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.selectedImages) {
                        RectangleProfileImageView(selectedImage: $0)
                    }
                    ForEach(viewModel.selectedImages.count ..< maximumToSelect, id: \.self) { _ in
                        RectangleProfileImageView(selectedImage: .init(state: .placeholder))
                    }
                }

                HStack {
                    PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.selectedItems,
                                 maxSelectionCount: maximumToSelect,
                                 selectionBehavior: .ordered,
                                 matching: .any(of: [.images, .not(.screenshots)]),
                                 preferredItemEncoding: .automatic,
                                 photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .font(.system(size: 60))
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    }.buttonStyle(.borderless)
                        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
class ExampleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedItems: [PhotosPickerItem] = [] {
        didSet { loadItems(selectedItems) }
    }

    @Published var selectedImages: [ImageRequest] = []

    private var task: Task<Void, Never>?
}

// MARK: - ExampleError

extension ExampleViewModel {
    enum ExampleError: Error {
        case unableToTransfer
        case unableToCreateImage
    }
}

// MARK: - Private implementation

private extension ExampleViewModel {
    // Fetch them concurrently, showing progress view for each while it is underway

    func loadItems(_ pickerItems: [PhotosPickerItem]) {
        task?.cancel()

        // show progress view for all the requests we are about to start

        selectedImages = pickerItems.indices.map { _ in
            ImageRequest(state: .inProgress)
        }

        // create tasks for each of the images

        task = Task {
            await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
                for (index, item) in pickerItems.enumerated() {
                    group.addTask { @MainActor [self] in
                        selectedImages[index] = await imageRequest(for: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func imageRequest(for item: PhotosPickerItem) async -> ImageRequest {
        do {
            return try await ImageRequest(state: .success(image(for: item)))
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return ImageRequest(state: .failure(error))
        }
    }

    func image(for item: PhotosPickerItem) async throws -> Image {
        guard let data = try await item.loadTransferable(type: Data.self) else {
            throw ExampleError.unableToTransfer
        }

        guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw ExampleError.unableToCreateImage
        }

        return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}

struct ImageRequest: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let state: State
}

extension ImageRequest {
    enum State {
        case placeholder
        case inProgress
        case failure(Error)
        case success(Image)
    }
}

struct RectangleProfileImageView: View {
    let selectedImage: ImageRequest
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: 108, height: 134)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if case .success(let image) = selectedImage.state {
                // just show fetched image

                image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            } else {
                // show frame

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: cellSize.width, height: cellSize.height)

                // show appropriate placeholder image if we have one, show spinner if not

                if let image = selectedImage.state.image {
                    image
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 23)
                } else {
                    ProgressView()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ImageRequest.State {
    var image: Image? {
        switch self {
        case .placeholder:        return Image(systemName: "photo.fill")
        case .failure:            return Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle.fill")
        case .success(let image): return image
        case .inProgress:         return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I have incorporated a few unrelated observations in the above:

- Rather than an `Image` property and a Boolean for `hasFailed`, I would use an enumeration, which is either `.placeholder`, `.inProgress`, `.failure(Error)` or `.success(Image)`.

  The idea is that this correctly captures the mutually exclusive fetch state (e.g., you only have an image if it was successful, you only have an `Error` if it failed, etc.). Note, while we do not use it yet, the `.failure` state captures *why* it failed. It might not be critical at this point, but it is generally better to capture the error in case you later want to provide a UI regarding the nature of the failure.
- IMHO, in the spirit of “separation of responsibilities”, model objects managed by the view model should not be vending views (the `rectangleView`). I have separated the model object (I called it `ImageRequest`) from the view that presents it (I called that `RectangleProfileImageView`).
- I hate seeing the cell size code sprinkled in different types. It invites problems when you later go to change the cell size and forget some spots (especially for those unusual error states).

  This is a matter of taste, but I retired `RectangleFailedImage` and `RectanglePlaceHolderImage` and incorporated all of this in `RectangleProfileImageView`. That is up to you, but avoid sprinkling magical constants throughout your source. If you want to keep these three different `View` types, just move the size constants into some shared namespace.

Comment: This is a 10X answer, really easy to follow